# Integrating Paypal checkout with Demandware and Oracle JDE

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, jdedwards, demandware

We have an e-commerce site powered by Demandware, and we are looking to integrate Paypal as a payment option. We use Oracle JDE to manage our orders.  We were told it will be about 96 hours to integrate Paypal to DemandWare and 200 hours to do the development work on JDE.  Does this sound reasonable?

Comment: Please elaborate your question --SO Review

Comment: Hi @IsettyRavitejakumar what is not clear for you? Because, he is asking about estimates, if this is reasonable estimates for such integration.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure for PayPal as a payment point, but I know that typical Demandware third party integration for payments with known integration point is ~100h. For example estimate for Cybersource, as Payment Service Provider, could be near 120h.

But according to 200h from Oracle JDE looks to be overestimated, as they should already have a PayPal support and will need only to configure it to your account. If they don't, and I don't believe it, you shouldn't pay for integration that they will reuse for other clients.

So answering your question: "Does this sound reasonable?" - "Not really."

Comment: Thanks!  This is helpful. Do you mean to say that Oracle JDE is already set up to handle PayPal and that they really just need to configure it? (Just so I am clear....)

Comment: Yes that what I was meaning, but I can't say it for sure. Nowadays 99% working with Paypal and it's sounds weird to me that for so common integration someone need 200h.

Comment: I agree that the Oracle JDE estimate sounds unreasonable. But there may be factors that would make it reasonable. Such as requiring a re-architecting of the entire payment processing module because it was never designed to support more than 1 payment processor. (Which would have been a bad design decision on the implementor's part.)